# How many times the ServiceLocator does do lookup operation in this case

Tags: java

Could you please help me in understanding this ServiceLocator class which is present in our Project

This is our `ServiceLocator` class

```
public class ServiceLocator
{
    private static ServiceLocator   instance;

    private Context                 initalContext;
    private Map                     cache;

    // return the singelton service locator
    public static ServiceLocator getInstance ()
            throws ServiceLocatorException
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ServiceLocator();
        return instance;
    }

    private ServiceLocator ()
    {
        try
        {
            this.initalContext = new InitialContext();
            this.cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            System.err.printf("Error in CTX lookup");
        }
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource (String dataSourceName)
    {
        DataSource datasource = null;
        try
        {
            if (this.cache.containsKey(dataSourceName))
                datasource = (DataSource)this.cache.get(dataSourceName);
            else
            {
                Context envContext = (Context)initalContext
                        .lookup("java:comp/env");
                datasource = (DataSource)envContext
                        .lookup(dataSourceName);
                this.cache.put(dataSourceName, datasource);
            }
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            System.err.printf("Error in CTX lookup");
        }
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

I have few questions with respect to the above code .

1. Is it necessary to make it as singleton Or a static synchronized method ??
2. Why is it that the dataSourceName is put under the map cache ??  (What happens if there are 10 concurrent users  does it do a look up  operation 10 times or 1 time )
3. Is it that only one User can use Database at one time??

For your reference this is the client that is using this Service Locator

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyObject.class);

private Connection con;
private DataSource dataSource;

public MyObject()
{
    this.dataSource = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getDataSource("jdbc/mydatabase");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: is it needed as a singleton: in short, yes if you want to share it across other threads or locations. A singleton is a static method. In this case you can even argue it ought to be synchronized, though some people prefer implementing them using an enum to avoid needing synchronized.

The why:
The servicelocator class was made singleton so that from multiple locations you can call methods on the same object, without creating it anew.

The reason for using singletons is either because constructing an instance takes so much resources you don't want to do it more than once, or because you want to make sure you only use the 1 instance across all calls to the method.

In this case, it is a singleton because the servicelocator caches named datasources which can be reused when it is called from anywhere else in your code.

However this singleton you post is not threadsafe. if you use it in a multithreaded environment (like in an application server) then there is a possibility that 2 threads both try to get the singleton. the first thread might get a different singleton with cache than the second one.

(second and any subsequent call will get the actual singleton instance).

Worse, in my opinion, is that the accessor code to the internal cache is not threadsafe either.
the worst case scenario here is only that you do a double looking of a datasource and one of the two results from the lookup gets dropped again. Since the author of the singleton uses synchronizedMap, the get/put is synchronized. But the decision *to* put is not. there is still a race condition here.

2: Why is it put in cache:

basically if you call getDataSource("abc") several times in a row, only the first time the datasource is looked up/loaded. the other times the code will find the datasource in the cache, and will return it directly.

3: good question :) it depends on your configuration. It is relatively safe to say no, many users/threads can access the database at the same time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html
states that a basic datasource only manages 1 connection. The use of singleton means all threads can access the same datasource at the same time, so if the single-connection datasource is used, this will cause trouble.

However the most common use of datasource is a pooleddatasource which represents a group of connections. In this case accessing it from many locations will give each individual thread it's own database connection, making it safe. When a thread closes a connection, this will return the connection to the pool for use by someone else.

Comment: Excellent answer , Thank you very much sir for taking your time and answering my question .

Answer (score 1):

1. Every instance of your `ServiceLocator` has own cache of some beans (datasources, service, etc). Your ServiceLocator is not singleton because few threads can create few instances easy. For singleton implementation you can use:

   - `synchronized` static method
   - Pugh's solution (nested static class)
2. Next problem is `getDataSource()` method. You're right that few threads can break its implementation. Even service locator is singleton you have not synchronization on your cache. Every dataSource has own connection pool. So you will get problem with connection count to your DB.
3. Number of User depends on `connection count` at datasource. If datasource has only one connection, yes, only one user is allowed.

Steps to solve your problems:

- make ServiceLocator as singleton or bean cache as singleton
- synchronize access to cache
- setup acceptable connection count

Comment: The Service Locator implementation which caches the result of lookup call,Since the same instance is used, will it not be a problem ??

Comment: @Kiran no it is not a problem. it is actually intended that multiple threads use the same instance. this is to facilitate the cached datasource. (if this is needed to be cached is another question)